# Search Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have following situation

I have 2 arrys

Following is answers array

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array (
        [id] => 4e28258263d2c4
        [answer] => Study Accounting 
        [question_id_fk] => 4e28258262d100 
        [correct] => 0 
        [result_text] => Thats a right answer 
        [order] => 1 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [id] => 4e28258266d896 
        [answer] => New York 
        [question_id_fk] => 4e28258265b752 
        [correct] => 0 
        [score] => 0.00 
        [result_text] => 
        [order] => 1
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [id] => 4e282582683870 
        [answer] => Yes 
        [question_id_fk] => 4e282582674ba0 
        [correct] => 0 
        [score] => 0.00 
        [hot_answer] => 0 
        [hot_email] => 
        [ordering] => 1 
        [result_text] => 
        [order] => 1 
    ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
        [id] => 4e282582698c23 
        [answer] => 2 
        [question_id_fk] => 4e282582689e80 
        [correct] => 0 
        [score] => 0.00 
        [hot_answer] => 0 
        [hot_email] => 
        [ordering] => 1 
        [result_text] => 
        [order] => 1 
    ) 
    [4] => Array ( 
        [id] => 4e2825826af072 
        [answer] => 1 
        [question_id_fk] => 4e2825826a0371 
        [correct] => 0 
        [score] => 0.00 
        [hot_answer] => 0 
        [hot_email] => 
        [ordering] => 1 
        [result_text] => 
        [order] => 1 
    ) 
    [5] => Array ( 
        [id] => 4e2825826d9638 
        [answer] => NYC 
        [question_id_fk] => 4e2825826ca998 
        [correct] => 0 
        [score] => 0.00 
        [hot_answer] => 0 
        [hot_email] => 
        [ordering] => 1 
        [result_text] => 
        [order] => 1 
    ) 
    [6] => Array ( 
        [id] => 4e2825826d9137 
        [answer] => Dallas 
        [question_id_fk] => 4e2825826ca998 
        [correct] => 0 
        [score] => 0.00 
        [hot_answer] => 0 
        [hot_email] => 
        [ordering] => 1 
        [result_text] => 
        [order] => 1 ) 
)
```

Here is Question List

```
 Array ( 
[0] => 4e28258262d100
[1] => 4e282582649464
[2] => 4e28258265b752 
[3] => 4e282582674ba0
[4] => 4e282582689e80 )

    foreach($questionList as $question){
        // I want to Get answers in array above which 
        // has $question.question_id = question_id_fk . One question can have multiple
        // answers

//Print Each question Id 
//Print answer , result_text and correct values from all answers found from AnswerList

     }
```

How do I search all answers for a question id from array . I need to get "correct" and "result_text" values for an answer .

Comment: Can you update your question to show an example of `QuestionList`?

Comment: This sounds a lot like a "do my homework" kind of question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$matches = array_filter ($answerList, function ($answer) use ($question) {
  return $question['id'] == $answer['question_id_fk'];
});
```

Now you can access every single entry.

If you want to reduce the structures to an array of primtive values (the values you are looking for) you ca do something like

```
$correct = array_reduce(
  $matches, 
  function ($result, $current) {
    $result[] = $current['correct'];
    return $result;
  }, 
  array()
);
```

---

### Update

I would suggest to reorder your `$answerList`

```
$answerListOrderedByQuestionId = array_reduce (
  $answerList, 
  function ($result, $answer) {
    if (!array_key_exists($answer['question_id_fk'], $result))
      $result[$answer['question_id_fk']] = array();

    $result[$answer['question_id_fk']][] = $answer;

    return $result;
  }, 
  array()
);
```

This should now be an associative array with the key the question-id. Now you can easily access every single answer for a given question.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($questionList as $question)
{
  if ($question['id'] == /*id we want to match*/)
  {
    // $question is now your match
    //   $question['correct']
    //   $queestion['result_text']
  }
}
```

---

If I understand your comment correctly:

```
// go through each aquestion
foreach ($questionList as $question)
{
  // for each question, we want the answer associated with it
  foreach ($answerList as $answer)
  {
    // make sure the ids match up
    if ($answer['question_id_fk'] == $question)
    {
      // $question & $answer is now your pair
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry for confusion I edited my question if you can take a look again . I have 2 arrays . I want to go through all questions and look for all answers from answerlist array

Comment: @user: See my update--is that closer to what you're looking for? If not, please provide more information (such as the answer array and what you're looking for as a desired result).

Comment: I need to print each question and answer thats why I am looping through questions

Answer (score -1):

The example only shows the answerlist array?

```
foreach ($questionList as $question)
{
  // for each question, look through the answers...
  foreach ($answerlist as $answer)
    if ($answer['question_id_fk'] == $question['id'])
    {
      // $answer matches the current question
    }
  }
}
```

On the other hand, you could process answerlist once, into an array indexed by question_id_fk, rather than searching the list for each question.